# Sql запрос UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

Что надо дописать, чтобы запрос сработал?

```
<?php mysql_query("UPDATE `settings` SET  `title` =  '$webtitle'"); ?>
<form action="setting.php" method="post">
<input class="setting_area" value="<? echo $webtitle; ?>" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="savetitle"></input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?
 if(!empty($_POST['web_title'])) {
     $web_title = $_POST['web_title'];
     mysql_query("UPDATE `settings` SET  `title` =  '$web_title'");
 }
 ?>

 <form action="setting.php" method="post"> 
   <input class="setting_area" value="<?= $web_title ?>" name="web_title"/>
   <br>
   <input type="submit" name="savetitle"/>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Убрать кавычки же:**

```
mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET  title =  '$webtitle'");
```

---

**И еще**. Данный запрос обновит ВСЕ записи в базе данных! В каждой записи будет значение, находящееся в `$webtitle`. Вы, скорее всего, хотите обновить какую-то одну запись. В таком случае следует дописать условие `WHERE`

Comment: Дело не в кавычках. У поля input нет параметра name, поэтому в базу всегда будет добавляться пустая строка.

Comment: @Зоркий, **именно** в кавычках. На HTML-код смотреть нет смысла - то уже не входит в проверку запросы к базе =) Да и к тому же, с чего то вы решили, что данное поле вообще используется в данном запросе !?

Comment: В запросе использованы обратные кавычки, они не могут служить причной ошибки. Название кнопки savetitle и попытка UPDATE поля title переменное $webtitle какбэ мягко намекают что поле используется в запросе.

Comment: Если выполнять код непосредственно в самой СУБД, то, да, ошибок не возникнет. PHP же этого не позволяет.

Answer (score -1):

А что Вам мешает перейти на PDO к примеру?

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;char=$charset", $user, $password);
    $pdo->beginTransaction();
    $pdo->exec("update settings set title=:web_title")
    $pdo->bindValue(':web_title',$_POST['web_title']);
    $pdo->commit();
```

Безопасность - всегда прежде всего.
Тем более проще и оптимизировано.